# Use raw_input to have user input variable name and use its value

Tags: python, raw-input

I am creating a financial modeling tool that a user can use. I want the user to be able to be able to enter what method they want to use by typing the variable name. However, with the code I have, the raw_input just gives out a string of what they entered, not the variable name itself

```
loose = 5
accurate = 10
extreme = 15

method = raw_input('Would you like the calculation to be loose, accurate, or extreme in its precision?: ") #the user would either type loose, accurate, or extreme

calculation = x*y*method #x and y is just a generic calculation and method should be equal to either 5, 10, or 15 based on whether the user chose loose, accurate, or extreme
```

I get an error that says method is not an int. What can I do to have it equal to the loose, accurate, or extreme values above?

Answer (score 6):

Change your variables into a dictionary and then use it to lookup the corresponding integer based on the user's input:

```
values = {'loose': 5,
          'accurate': 10,
          'extreme': 15}

method = raw_input('Would you like the calculation to be loose, accurate, or extreme in its precision?: ') #the user would either type loose, accurate, or extreme

calculation = x*y*values[method] #x and y is just a generic calculation and method should be equal to either 5, 10, or 15
```

You can also use `values.get(method, 0)` in place of `values[method]`, if the users enters something that is not in  your dictionary then `0` will be used.

Comment: This is a good way to do it.  You will just need to make sure to handle the situation where someone puts in a method that doesn't match one of your choices.

Comment: @Isowen Good point; I edited to show use of `values.get(method, 0)` which would handle the case of an input not being in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The best</s>One way would be something like:

```
loose = 5
accurate = 10
extreme = 15

method_selection = raw_input('Would you like the calculation to be loose, accurate, or extreme in its precision?: ')

if method_selection == "loose":
    method = loose
elif method_selection == "accurate":
    method = accurate
else:
    method = extreme

calculation = x*y*method
```

Adjust the order of the if statements to give you the proper "default" (ie someone puts in a method that doesn't match one of yours).

Comment: The best way? I initially thought of this as well, but using a dictionary as per Jkdc's answer is much better. You can simply add keys to the dictionary instead of adding if/else code. Not to mention the simplicity and ability to add/remove keys at run-time.

Comment: I agree, probably not the best way.  Updating to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

A direct solution is to use `eval`.

```
method = eval(raw_input(...))
```

Note, that it's not recommended to use `eval`, since it sets a user free to execute whatever he/she wants.

Comment: While a potential method, it is usually best to avoid `eval` if at all possible.

Comment: @ Yeah, I've added that to the answer along with an explanation. Yet, it is an option one should know.